# Can I find yesterday's date from the first of a given month?

Tags: sql-server

My question is this:-
When I use the following query:-

```
SELECT dateadd(dd,-1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

on the first of the month eg 2018-10-01 would I get the correct Date and Month
eg 2018-09-30 ?
Obviously I can't test this until the first of the month (4 days from now)
and would like to know as it would solve a problem for me. This would be run on MSSQL Server 2016 Standard edition Server 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I believe you will

Comment: I changed your question title, since it was misleading (at least, it misled me).

Comment: Test it? `SELECT dateadd(dd,-1, cast('2018/10/01' as date))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I should have thought of that myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will give you yesterdays date (even if first day of a month or year).

(No need to CAST GETDATE() to date, btw. Unless you want to avoid > 23:59:59.997 to give you tomorrows date.)